# run multiple commands on remote server

Tags: java, linux, ssh, jsch

So far I've managed to connect, run a single command and then disconnect. The problem I'm having is running a second, third, etc command thereafter.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            JSch js = new JSch();
            Session session = js.getSession("myuser", "myhost", 22);
            session.setPassword("mypassword");
            Properties properties = new Properties() {
                {
                    put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                }
            };
            session.setConfig(properties);
            session.connect();

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");

            ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) channel;
            channelExec.setCommand("ls");
            channelExec.setErrStream(System.err);
            channelExec.connect();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(channelExec.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

//            This part doesn't work. It causes the program to hang.
//            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(channelExec.getOutputStream()));
//            writer.write("cd Downloads");
//            writer.write("ls");
//            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(channelExec.getInputStream()));
//            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
//                System.out.println(line);
//            }

            channelExec.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();

            System.out.println("Exit code: " + channelExec.getExitStatus());
        } catch (JSchException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

I've tried using the `ChannelExec` `OutputStream` but that just caused the program to do nothing so I suspect that's not the way to go.

What should I add to print the contents following the commands `cd Downloads` and `ls` for example after the first `ls` output has been printed?

Comment: could you be more specific. Where did you try to connect to, a ssh or some other?

Comment: The code that you posted looks like it only runs one command, so I guess it's working fine? Could you edit your post to contain the code you wrote which isn't working? And explain exactly how it's failing?

Comment: @Kenster: I've added the broken code

Answer (score 1):

Seperate your commands with ";"
eg:

`String command1="cd mydeploy/tools/Deploy/scripts/; ls -ltr;./conn_testing.ksh";`